# How can I align two (disconnected) nodes in GraphViz?

Tags: graphviz

Suppose I have the GraphViz graph:

```
digraph G {
a->b->d;
c->d;
}
```

How can I make `a` and `c` be aligned vertically, i.e. appear at the same height?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align them using grouping and a group-scope attribute:

```
digraph G {
{rank = same; a; c;}
a->b->d;
c->d;
}
```

[image]

Note that if your `rankdir` value is different, this alignment will not be vertical: e.g. if `rankdir=LR` then `a` and `c` will be horizontally aligned to the same position - with the arrows pointing rightwards.